# Верстка bootstrap 3

Tags: веб-программирование, вёрстка, bootstrap

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть макет как на картинке. Текст размещается как бы в контейнере (слева отступ есть)  а вот картинка получается вне контейнера. Получается, что просто две колонки не сделать. Как правильно было бы решить эту проблему?
[image: Макет]

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял, то будет так.

Comment: Не совсем. В таком случае, из-за использования класса контейнера, появляется отступ справа, а нужно чтобы картинка была прибита к правой части (чтоб не было отступа), а содержимое с текстом как бы было в контейнере (был типичный отступ слева для контейнера).

Comment: Тогда создайте класс с padding: 0; и пропишите его контейнерам с классами row и container. Тогда отступ у картинки исчезнет, а у текста останется.